# 'object Object' in firefox wehn referencing jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First time i've used jquery and I'm in trouble .
I used the following code in html :

```
<ul>
    <li>hello </li>
    <li>hello 2</li>
    <li>hello 3</li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var lis = jQuery('ul li')
console.log(lis)
</script>
```

When I checked my version , It was 2.0.3 .

But I opened firefox and used Inspect element to check the console , 
it returns

```
[17:57:32.367] [object Object]
instead of [<li>hello</li>]
```

Actually I'm learning via Tuts free courses (Hello Jquery by jeffery way) at this link; and he gets different output

Comment: What you have ***is*** is an object, a jQuery object, not a string

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do. Effectively you're saying "The output isn't right" and we're saying it is. What you should do next depends on what you need to do.

Comment: `var lis = $('ul li').val()`

Comment: @mdesdev - `li`'s dont have a `val()` only fields do.

Comment: try `console.log(lis.get())`

Comment: var lis = $('ul li').html() or var lis = $('ul li').text()

Comment: Actually I'm learning via Tuts free courses (Hello Jquery by jeffery way) at this [link](http://freecourses.tutsplus.com/30-days-to-learn-jquery/hello-jquery.html); and he gets different output

Comment: @Jamiec you're right, like @Ali said, must be `var lis = $('ul li').text();` that's gonna return all text values or `var lis = $('ul li').html();` which'll in this case return the 1st list item text value. But if he want to return whole html like `<li>hello</li>` then he must use `var lis = $('ul').html();`

Answer (score 1):

Because `jQuery('ul li')` returns a DOM object. If you want to get internal html of li or ul then you can try it

```
jQuery('ul').html() // for ul internal html
jQuery('ul li').html() // for li html
```

or you can also use that object like `jQuery(lis).html()`

Comment: Actually the basic jQuery selector returns a jQuery object, but your answer still applies. And you can there just do lis.html(), without having to wrap in the jQuery constructor again.

Comment: But how did jefferey way get different output...?

Answer (score 0):

It returns that because it's just jquery object(element). You are just selecting that list item, not the content in it. Add `.text()` function to your variable for getting contents of selector:

```
var lis = jQuery('ul li').text();
console.log(lis);
```

Comment: Actually I'm learning via Tuts free courses (Hello Jquery by jeffery way) at this link; and he gets different output